# BitPay API notifications: security risk?

Tags: php, api, security, notifications

I'm currently implementing the BitPay API (in PHP). All works fine but I'm a bit worried about a possible security risk when receiving notifications.

The BitPay API sends these notifications with status updates using a **POST** request to a given notification url containing a **JSON string** like this:

`{
  "id": "123BitPayInvoiceID",
  "url": "https://bitpay.com/invoice?id=123BitPayInvoiceID",
  "posData": "6G38ZL",
  "status": "paid",
  "btcPrice": "0.0512",
  "price": 29.14,
  "currency": "USD",
  "invoiceTime": 1407881291063,
  "expirationTime": 1407882191063,
  "currentTime": 1407882058099,
  "btcPaid": "0.0512",
  "rate": 568.69,
  "exceptionStatus": false,
  "bitpay":
    {
      "id": "123BitPayInvoiceID",
      "url": "https://bitpay.com/invoice?id=123BitPayInvoiceID",
      "posData": "{\"paymentID\":\"123PAYMENTID\",\"orderID\":\"123ORDERID\"}",
      "status": "confirmed",
      "btcPrice": "0.0512",
      "price": 29.14,
      "currency": "USD",
      "invoiceTime": 1407881291063,
      "expirationTime": 1407882191063,
      "currentTime": 1407882058099,
      "btcPaid": "0.0512",
      "rate": 568.69,
      "exceptionStatus": false
    }
}`

When I lookup the payment in our database I want to change it to 'confirmed'.

It seems to me this is a security risk, since anyone can send fake notifications; someone who started the payment and wants that payment to be confirmed can send this request with status set to 'confirmed'.

**My questions:**

1. Should I be worried in the first place? I could check where the request is from, use a notification Url that is not easy to guess etc. but I still would not feel comfortable security-wise;
2. I could always distrust any notification and send a status request to the API when a notification comes in. Would this be a good practice?;
3. Are there any other (better) ways you know of to safely use these notifications?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the advice you are looking for is in their docs...

https://bitpay.com/docs/invoice-callbacks

> We would advise you to open a non-standard port and specify that port
>   within the notificationURL instead of white listing BitPay IP
>   addresses as they are subject to change without notice. Since we are
>   not yet signing these notifications they should not be trusted
>   outright. We recommend verifying these notifications against our API
>   when they are received to make sure the data presented is authentic.
>   For example when an invoice paid notification comes in, you should
>   make a request to our API to check the status of that invoice to make
>   sure it was actually paid. This provides additional security in
>   verifying paid orders.